# vcalendar wrong time for outlook

Tags: java, spring, outlook, icalendar, vcalendar

I am sending localtime in the ics file but outlook is converting it to the corresponding timezone

.ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Gr Inc//Gr Calendar//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:calendar.10@gmdf.co
DTSTAMP:20150318T225646Z
DTSTART:20150321T000000
DTEND:20150321T010000
SUMMARY:test 6
DESCRIPTION:5-7pm pacific time
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:test 6
TRIGGER:-PT5H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

In the above invite, it sets the invitation to 5:30 to 6:30, but I expect it to 1:00 to 2:00, i.e it should not convert to local calendar timezone.

How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

It’s doing exactly what you have told it to do - use the local time.

If you don’t want that then you should send time in UTC time format or Timezone format.

https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-5-date-time.html